# Merge two dataframes using pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, merge

First of all thank you for your help.

I have two dataframes row indexed by date (DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM) as follows:

```
DF1
        date               temp       wind 
0   31-12-2002 23:00       12.3       80   
1   01-01-2004 00:00       15.2       NAN
2   01-01-2004 01:00       18.4       NAN 
                 ........
```

```
DF2
        date               temp       wind 
0   31-12-2002 23:00       14.5       86   
1   01-01-2003 00:00       28.7       98
2   01-01-2003 01:00       26.7       88
                ........
n   01-01-2004 00:00       34.5       23 
m   01-01-2004 01:00       35.7       NAN
```

```
MergedDF
        date               temp       wind 
0   31-12-2002 23:00       12.3       80
1   01-01-2003 00:00       28.7       98
2   01-01-2003 01:00       26.7       88
                ........
n   01-01-2004 00:00       15.2       23 
m   01-01-2004 01:00       18.4       NAN
```

In DF1 there's one whole year (2003) missing and also some NAN values in the rest of the years.
Basically I want to merge both dataframes, adding the year missing and replacing NAN values if this information is in DF2.

Someone could help me? I don't know very well how to implement this on python/pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MergedDF = df1.append(df2).groupby('date', as_index=False).first()
```

`as_index=False` option of [`group_by`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is useful to keep the same table index in the aggregated output.

[`.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) will keep the first non-null value for each date.